# Проблема при добалении позиций в заказ покупателя

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Проблема кроется в области добавления позиций к заказу, т.к. пустой заказ создается без проблем. Не могу понять что не так, добавляю так:

```
$positionList = new EntityList($this->moysklad);
$positionList->push(Product::query($this->moysklad)->byId($uuid));
```

Текст ошибки при создании заказа:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: `POST https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/customerorder` resulted in a `412 Precondition Failed` response' in /vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113

Comment: 412 ошибка означает "Не указан обязательный параметр строки запроса или поле структуры JSON"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При добавления товара к заказу, необходимо передать 2 поля: `assortment` и `quatity`
Позиции можно передавать сразу массивом, размером не более 100.

```
$pos = array(
    "quantity"      => $quantity,
    "assortment"    => array("meta"=>array(
        "href"          => "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/".$idmy,
        "metadataHref"  => "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/metadata",
        "type"          => "product",
        "mediaType"     => "application/json"   
                        ))
                    );
$poslist[] = $pos;
```

В `href` используется `id` товара